# Exporting Sharepoint to excel form

Tags: sharepoint, office365, powerapps, sharepoint-list

Situation/requirement: I have a sharepoint list. The entries in this sharepoint list go as entry to an excel sheet which is a form to be printed out. I am looking into a functionality flow/app that could be used to export the new entries to fill and print out to an excel template. Any thoughts?

Comment: from what you had described, the microsoft forms app fits better for the purpose.. (imho).

Answer (score 0):

@Gaurav Vasishth,

Power Automate offers a connector that could update Excel file on the cloud.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/#update-a-row

You can use this connector to update rows or create worksheet/table.

BR